# Can a serialized simple java object be deserialized by C#?

Tags: c#, java, .net, serialization, deserialization

Assuming all fields of a java class are java primitives, if such an object has been serialized, can it be successfully deserialized  by C# into an instance of an "equivalent" C# class?

Is the reverse possible - C# to java?

---

I realise there are many language agnostic formats, such as XML that could be *used* to get the job done. I am more interested in whether using the *native* serialized data is feasible.

Comment: No I haven't tried it. Thought I would ask first in case it's simply not possible.

Answer (score 5):

The formats of serialized streams are available. I think you can write a class easily to parse the byte stream and create the required class in C#.

An article that specifies the serialized format:
http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2915

Comment: This is more what I was wondering. My C# knowledge is very limited, but if it can be described it can be programmed...

Comment: It is just byte[] traversal. You can look at a sample java code to traverse the serialization bytes here [link](https://github.com/smartplatf/a-utilities/blob/master/src/main/java/org/anon/utilities/serialize/srdr/SerialStreamReader.java). We have modified the default serialization, so our traversal is a little different. We have used to detect dirty fields.

Comment: A more formal definition of the serialization format can be [found in the official Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html).

Answer (score 2):

[WOX](http://woxserializer.sourceforge.net/) will be helpful to achieve interoperable serialization.
it can `serialize/deserialize` `Java/C#` objects `into/from` standard `XML`(platform independent)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, at least not using the native serialization libraries that both frameworks provide, as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183287/deserializing-a-java-serialized-file-in-c-sharp) previous SO post.

If you want to achieve cross language serialization/deserialization, you could resort to XML ([XSTream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for Java, [XStream-dot-net](https://code.google.com/p/xstream-dot-net/) for C#) or [WOX](http://woxserializer.sourceforge.net/):

> WOX is an XML serializer for Java and C# objects. In other words, WOX
>   is a library (woxSerializer.jar for Java, and woxSerializer.dll for
>   C#) to serialize Java and C# objects to XML and back again.

Comment: This is not correct. The Java serialization format is openly documented and stable since Java version 1.1.7. Assuming that all fields of a Java class are Java primitives, there is no reason that you can't deserialize a Java object into C#, except that you would have to implement the parser yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with including another dependency, you might consider using an object database such as [db4o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Db4o) for the job. I haven't tried this myself, but according the Wikipedia article,

> db4o uses a custom feature called "generic reflector" to represent class information, when class definitions are not available, which allows to use it in a mixed Java-.NET environment, for example Java client - .NET server and vice versa.

You can find more information about the above-mentioned reflection API [here](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/java/reference/Content/implementation_strategies/db4o_reflection_api.htm) and [here](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/java/reference/Content/implementation_strategies/db4o_reflection_api/using_db4o_reflection_api.htm).

In a nutshell, this would lead to a system where you store your Java/C# objects to an (embedded) database (i.e., without client/server architecture, but by loading a single file that contains the whole database) and retrieve C#/Java objects from the database afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this document with a high amount of success to parse data stored in serialized format on a database:

http://www.jtech.ua.es/j2ee/2005-2006/modulos/rmi/recursos/serial-1.5.0.pdf

The most meaningful info for me was from page 63 to 68.

In my case I had the source code used to serialize the data which was useful to both identify fields and read the data when was written in a non standard way using the ISerializable.WriteObject/ReadObject calls.

I don't know the reason but my serialized data had not "handler" field on any object, it would take 0 bytes. Other than that, everything followed the docs but it gets kind of tricky if you have never done such kind of tasks before

As noted on some comment, this is a good base even if it's written in java:

https://github.com/smartplatf/a-utilities/blob/master/src/main/java/org/anon/utilities/serialize/srdr/SerialStreamReader.java