# Sending objects between a java client and a C# server (using TCP and BinaryFormatter)

Tags: c#, tcp, binaryformatter

I'm trying to develop client server application which can transfer **Files** and **Strings** from **Client to Server**. I'm new to TCP, sockets and server transactions.

Client side is written in Java and Server Side is Written in C#

what I'm trying to do in Server(C#) , get all the bytes and cast it to an Object, because I'm sending all the Objects from client side in *Object type*. then i wanted to cast to File or String

but in this line of code I'm getting an error

```
Object myObject = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
```

*Server side:-*

```
private void ClientHandler(object client)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];

        tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        Console.WriteLine("Client Handler Started!");

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server waiting for commands\n");

                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();


                while ((bytesRead = tcpClient.Client.Receive(buffer)) > 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("bytes received :- " + bytesRead);

                    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);                        

                }
                try
                {

                    memStream.Position = 0;

                    Object myObject = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
                    // After this cast it to String or File 

                }
                catch(Exception exp)
                {                       
                    Console.WriteLine(exp.ToString());
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                //a socket error has occured
                Console.WriteLine("a socket error has occured!!!");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: show the inner exception of catch ?

Comment: Exception is "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed"

Comment: I've never actually tried this before, but I'm pretty sure that you can't use .NET `BinaryFormatter` to deserialize an object that was serialized using Java. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801967/can-a-serialized-simple-java-object-be-deserialized-by-c

Comment: Please add to question your serializable object.

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is for .NET-only scenarios. Why not use SOAP between the two, since both platforms support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary formatter places a header on the binary stream which represents a .NET type. You can not use that to send 'object' meaning to a non .net client.

Instead you will have to serialise to XML or Json and provide a local model and deserialisation in your client.